# 'Items' is not defined error when passing value to another component

Tags: reactjs

I am getting ./src/App.js Line 27:  'Items' is not defined  react/jsx-no-undef 
while trying to pass state to a another component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios'

class App extends Component {
    // Added this:
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Assign state itself, and a default value for items
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };

    }
    componentWillMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.opendota.com/api/proMatches').then(res => {
        this.setState({ items: res.data });

        });
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="app">
            <Items items={this.state.items} />  
            </div></blink></blink>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: replace `componentWillMount()` with `componentDidMount()`

Comment: nope still got same error

Comment: Where did you define `Items` component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Errors:- (1) import `Items` component (2) use `componentDidMount()` instead of `componentWillMount()` (3) use ternary operator in JSX `this.state.items.length > 0` for displaying items after getting response

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Items from './Items';

class App extends Component {
    // Added this:
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        // Assign state itself, and a default value for items
        this.state = {
            items: []
        };

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        axios.get('https://api.opendota.com/api/proMatches').then(res => {
        this.setState({ items: res.data });

        });
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div className="app">
            {
                this.state.items.length > 0 ?
                <Items items={this.state.items} />  : null
            }
            </div></blink></blink>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not trying to use a component called `Items` without importing it first:

`<Items items={this.state.items} />`

Every component that you use must be imported first:

```
import { Items } from "DIRECTORY"
```

Answer (score 0):

App is top component and Items is child component.To use any child component or pass any kind props or state ,it has to be imported first .

There can be another issue to it since you are using state and if the child component Items  is rerendered due to any change ,then state of your APP component will also reset.